# Android: How to style to center following "fake" modal layout above the transparent activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, styling

I have following transparent activity with linear layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to create layout like this (Yes, i know that background is from iOS device, but does not matter in this case)
It means, how to style content of the activity, "modal window" to be centered, to have margins, icons, etc:

[image]

Could somebody tell me how i should easy and effectively style layout like this?

Many Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Create a transparent `Activity` and show whatever you want in it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/2700683#2700683

Comment: Yes, i have transparent activity already created, but i asked about how to style content of the activity, it means. "modal window" to be centered, to have margins, etc..

Comment: Just design your layout and then put it inside a `FrameLayout` with your margins. e.g. `<FrameLayout layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="match_parent" layout_marginLeft="16dp" layout_marginRight="16dp"> <include layout="@layout/modal_dialog" layout_width="match_parent" layout_height="wrap_content" layout_gravity="center_vertical" /> </FrameLayout>`

Comment: And included layout modal_dialog inside is FrameLaout, Linear layout or what?